# How to display directory size of the n most recent additions in bash

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls, du

I'd like to display the 10 most recently added directories, for instance with:

```
ls -tlh | head -20
```

However, I'd also like to include directory size with with du. But I can't seem to figure out how to get the size of only the 10 most recent additions - querying all dirs would take far too long.

```
du --max-depth=1 | head -20
```

..doesn't seem to work. So I'm looking for a way to display both date modified and directory size of the 10 most recently modified dirs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print the directory size of the 10 most recently modified dirs:

```
for dir in $(ls -t -c1 | head -20); do 
    echo $(du -sh $dir 2>/dev/null)
done
```

As a one liner:

```
for dir in $(ls -t -c1 | head -20); do echo $(du -sh $dir 2>/dev/null) ; done
```

Comment: This gives me a different output than the "ls | head -10"; which did provide me with the 10 most recent dirs. But the above line gives me a mix of dates, some from 2014 and 2013.

Comment: That's weird, man page of `ls` states _"-t   sort by modification time, newest first"_ so the results from `ls -t -c1` should be listed by modification time. Plain `ls` will print the results sorted alphabetically

Comment: I meant the `ls -tlh | head -20`; but I got it to work with just adding that to the line above; making `for dir in $(ls -t | head -20); do echo $(du -sh $dir 2>/dev/null) ; done` do what I need :)